# Python - How to add local variables based on number of n provided

Tags: python

I have a function that takes in a list and n number. I'd like to create something like this:

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    if n == 1:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            res = [lst[i], lst[i+1]]
            return res
    if n == 2:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            res2 = [lst[i], lst[i+1], lst[i+2]]
            return res2
```

Only I dont want to write `n == 2, n == 3... n == n`. More specifically, if my `def create_list_sets(lst, n)` takes `n == 4` I want res to eqaul `[lst[i], lst[i+1], lst[i+2], lst[i+3], lst[i+4]]`, without hardcoding this in.

Here is the full code I'm working on:

```
###########
# Library #
###########

def number_to_be_tested():
    number_tested = 34278698769876978697687693454
    return number_tested


def number_split(object):
    lst = []
    string_the_number = str(object)
    for digit in string_the_number:
        lst.append(int(digit))
    return lst


def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    if n == 1:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            res = [lst[i], lst[i+1]]
            return res
    if n == 2:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            res2 = [lst[i], lst[i+1], lst[i+2]]
            return res2

##################################
# Script / Application / Program #
##################################

def main():
    test_number = number_to_be_tested()
    test_lst = number_split(test_number)
    list_sets = test_lst(test_lst, 2)
    print list_sets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I accomplish my goal? Also as you can see, it will create a Traceback at the end of the program, I'm not concerned about this atm -- that said, if you know how to also help me in this, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: When a function hits `return`, it stops. Returning inside a loop doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: A simple loop/comprehension probably works:  `[lst[i+j] for j in range(n+1)]` ... `lst[i:i+n+1]` probably works too ... But I'm not 100% sure that solves your problem.  You seem to be returning after the first iteration of your loops over `i`, so I'm not sure what they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mgilson, By 'what they're trying to accomplish' it's me trying to accomplish. I am trying to learn python. For this self assignment, I am starting with a list of numbers, and trying to break them up into sets of 2,3,4 whatever n may be. Only thing is, I want to start each set with each item in the list. This would create a total of at most 28 new lists (depending if n == 1 or more). With the code I provided I am able to do it, but only if i specify what n could be. Because I am starting out, my ability to describe my desired route may be a bit unclear.

Comment: @user2357112, I'm aware of this... still working out proper Python techniques!

Comment: @Lefty -- I'm still not sure what you're going for here.  e.g. for `n == 2`, you could just write `return [lst[0], lst[1], lst[2]]` since `i` will always be 0 on the first iteration and then you return before you have a chance to do a second iteration.  What is the purpose of the loop over `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know n and have the full lst and the value of n you can use the append

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    res = []
    if n <= len(lst):
        for i in range(n):
           res.append([lst[i])
    return res
```

Note that this assumes that you want an empty list to return as an error  when `n > len(lst)`. If you just want to reset n to `len(lst)` if n is too large then use

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    res = []
    if n >= len(lst):
        n = len(lst) -1
    for i in range(n):
        res.append([lst[i], lst[i+1]])
    return res
```

my apologies for not being specific in my question. You have it right on the head. I do want one more functionality. if n ==4 i want what you provided. but I want it for each index. so: if n == 2 -> res = [lst[0], lst[1]], [lst[1], lst[2]], [lst[2], lst[3]], [lst[3], lst[4]]…] – Lefty 2 hours ago

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    res = []
    if n > len(lst):
        n = len(lst)
    for k in range(len(lst) - n + 1)
        tmp = []
        for i in range(n):
            tmp.append(lst[i+k])
        res.append(tmp)
    return res
```

Note that the inner loop can be replaced by a slice

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    j = len(lst)
    res = []
    if n > j:
        n = j
    for k in range(j - n + 1)
        res.append(lst[k:k+n])
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like this approach, however it doesnt appear to let me iterate over each item. Id like the ability to have this occur for each item. This allows me to do this for the first index, but not the second, third, fourth, all the way down to the end.

Comment: @Lefty Actually it loops over all the indices. given any n, it will create the entire list from index 0 through index n-1. That is if `n == 4` it will create `res = [lst[0], lst[1], lst[2], lst[3]] Isn,t that what you wanted?

Comment: my apologies for not being specific in my question. You have it right on the head. I do want one more functionality. if n ==4 i want what you provided. but I want it for each index. so: if n == 2 -> 
res = [lst[0], lst[1]], [lst[1], lst[2]], [lst[2], lst[3]], [lst[3], lst[4]]…]

Comment: @Lefty I think that I added what you wanted to the code. I have not had a chance to test it as It is late right now. However it should be the idea of what you want.

Comment: @Lefty If it is what you want, just hit the check mark. I have to go now.

Comment: had to go for the time. This was perfect! Thank you for your assistance and patience!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess what you want to do is simply:

```
lst = lst[:min(len(lst), n)]
```

This will give you all the elements up to n-1 or the full list

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be:

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    # multiple cases for value X
    if n == X:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            res = [lst[i], ..., lst[i+X]]
            return res
```

Your `for` loop executes only once, because you are `return`ing the `res`-like variables. So I will disregard the whole for loop and consider only the first value of `i`, i.e. zero.

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    # multiple cases here for X
    if n == X:
      return [lst[0], ..., lst[0+n]]
```

which could be restated like this:

```
def create_list_sets(lst, n):
    return lst[:max(min(n, len(lst)), 0)+1]
```